# Pipe to get data from Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angular2-pipe

My pipe is not returning the first name. 
When I am hardcode an name it's returning.
Why?

In the html:

```
{{photo.uid | userName}}
```

Pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { UserData } from './../providers/user-data';

@Pipe({name: 'userName'})
export class UserNamePipe implements PipeTransform {
  name: string;

   constructor(private userData:UserData){}

  transform(value:any, args:string[]) {
   this.userData.getSpeseficUserData(value).subscribe((data:any) => {
     this.name = data.firstName;
     return this.name;
   });
 }
}
```

getSpeseficUserData():

```
getSpeseficUserData(uid:any){
  return Observable.create((observer: any) => {
    firebase.database().ref('users/' + uid).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
        observer.next(snapshot.val());
    })
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see it in action : [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/P0Q18yCJn0zZb1xkbp7z)

first you have to return an observable in `transform` method  and use `async` pipe to show your data :

pipe:

```
transform(value:any, args:string[]) {
   return this.userData.getSpeseficUserData(value).map((data:any) => {
     this.name = data.firstName;
     return this.name;
   });
 }
```

template :

```
{{photo.uid | userName | async}}
```

Comment: I added a plunker example